# Is dnotify obsolete in kernel 4.x?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

Im reading the `fcntl` [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) and came across thw `dnotify`:

> File and directory change notification (dnotify)

It is suggested that new application should use `inotify` instead, but I think they are not the same since `inotify` works with `char *` paths making it suffering from file renaming (or cathing `MOVED_FROM`/`MOVED_TO` events) but `dnotify` works with file descriptors which is different:

```
int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, ... /* arg */ );
```

So as far as I can tell `dnotify` is not a subset of `inotify` neither vice versa.

Is it discouraged to use `dnotify` in newer kernel even if I want to subscribe on events by file descriptor, not by a file path as `inotify` allows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the manual page for `inotify_add_watch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_add_watch.2.html) closer, then yes it takes a path *but* it returns a "watch descriptor"

> for the filesystem object (inode) that corresponds to `pathname`

So the path is only used to locate the inode. Once that's done you have a reference to the inode and the name of the file can be changed without problems.

Comment: The question is why is not `ino_t` as in `stat` returned. Or can I safely cast inode returned by `inotify_add_watch` to `ino_t`?https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: @SomeName The documentation doesn't say anything about a way to go from a "watch descriptor" to the actual inode, only that the "watch descriptor" is a unique descriptor for the inode. Why do you need an `ino_t`? What is the real and actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: The problem with `watch_descriptor` is that we cannot use it to open the file. So we have to use the `char* path` again introducing races. This was the reason I asked about `dnotify` since it is operating on already opened file referring to by the file descriptor.

Comment: @SomeName Well, the inotify events seems to hold a filename, you could test if it's the "real" file-name after renaming?